# How Mongo $sort works?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

in my collection

```
{"subOrderId":"985409601"},
{"subOrderId":"87596401"},
{"subOrderId":"871997501"},
{"subOrderId":"871997401"},
{"subOrderId":"871997401"}
```

these types of entries are there and i'm applying sorting in "`subOrderId`" fields desc

Please Explain how its works in case numeric string `{numericOrdering: false}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this Query

```
db.DbCollection.aggregate( [
  {$addFields: {
      sortData: { $toInt: "$subOrderId" },
   }},
  { $sort : { sortData : 1} },
  {$project: {subOrderId:1}}
 ])
```

Comment: What is problem that query please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty straight forward, from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document):

> Optional. Flag that determines whether to compare numeric strings as numbers or as strings.
>
> If true, compare as numbers; i.e. "10" is greater than "2".
>
> If false, compare as strings; i.e. "10" is less than "2".
>
> Default is false.

When it is set to false it does a "normal" string compare, meaning anything that starts with "1" will be "smaller" than anything that starts with ">2" like "19519519512" < "2".